# Programmatically create component names

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple app in react which shows guides/tutorials.

Each guide has a different amount of steps, and each step is a component that I render in the body of my "Tutorial" component. I'm wondering how to programmatically call each element onto the screen. The approach I have now is as follows:

```
const tutorialSteps = {
    1: <Step1 />,
    2: <Step2 />,
    3: <Step3 />
  };
```

and then in my return statement of my function:

```
{tutorialSteps[step]}
```

(It should be noted that "step" is the a state variable in my component, which is updated based on the users progress in the guide)

As aforementioned, each tutorial is a different length, and I don't want to hardcode 99 steps in my dictionary (as this is bad practice for obvious reasons).

Is there anyway to dynamically call the component based on the current step?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A component is a component in React, at some point the compiler is going to have to know, so it's not something you could make dynamic with a string only.  IOW:  a string "Step1" in React will not automatically bind to `<Step1 />`.  But if you have things that are common in your steps, you could make a single component and get it's data from sort of file store / database.

Comment: Yeah I had things stored in a database before but because they’re large HTML files it was difficult to maintain and my boss told me I wasn’t allowed to lol. I was hoping for a better way but I suppose I’ll keep searching. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can do what you want, but you will still need to declare each stepX component in code - or are the contents of the steps dynamic too? You might need to provide more code in your question to show how the steps are constructed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if I'm missing something fundamental here, but why not something like this? (pseudo-code)

```js
const steps = [
  Step1,
  Step2,
  Step3,
];

render () {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const Component = steps[step];
  return <Component onNext={() => setStep(step + 1)} />
}
```

Comment: No no, you are exactly correct! Though that is what I’m doing currently, but the issue is I don’t know how many steps any given tutorial can have, so I cannot hard code the value

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct because it is almost identical to the solution that I did end up using, and this would work in context. I made a new main component for each individual guide, and then each guide controlled it's own steps with a hardcoded list. Thank you for the help!